# C# 6 namespace as string from a strongly typed namespace reference

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I want to get a namespace string from a strongly typed namespace reference in a similar way as C# 6 [nameof()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) works for types and type members.

```
namespace This.Is.My.Namespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string namespaceString = nameof(This.Is.My.Namespace);
            Console.Write(namespaceString);
        }
    }
}
```

But the result i get is only the last portion of the namespace (e.g. "Namespace"). I'm targeting .NET 4.6

Is this possible?

REMARK: I want to be able to reference any available namespace, not only the containing one.

Comment: The first sentence from the page you linked to says "Used to obtain **the simple (unqualified) string name** of a variable, type, or member". But this sounds like an X-Y problem: why do you need to do this to get the namespace name when you can get it from a type in that namespace?

Comment: @stuartd for example i want to filter certain types coming from an assembly reflection

Comment: Why don't you then show an example of what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @stuartd Because this is more general question. I'm looking for a clean and flexible way to express the namespace not as a hardcoded literal which will be hard to refactor later.

Answer (score 2):

This should work...

```
var myType = this.GetType();
var namespaceString = myType.Namespace;
```

Comment: `typeof(this)` won't compile.  Maybe `this.GetType()` or `typeof(Program)`.

Comment: And you don´t know any Type within that namespace? A `Namespace` without any types in it will not be accessible at runtime to my knowledge, since it will not contain anything.

Comment: @Marcus it is odd to choose a specific type if you have a number of types contained in the same namespace. I really like the clearness of the nameof() syntax.

Comment: But what do you think a namespace really is, because I think you misunderstand the concept. A namespace is just a _container_. It really is nothing and there is no reference to it (does not occupy memory) at runtime. Without a Type - the namespace does not exist in a runtime context. Maybe we could help better if you broaden your question and explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Marcus Yes, the namespace is just a container to organize your code. My concrete case is to filter certain types coming from an assembly reflection, but i think mine is more general question. I'm looking for a clean and flexible way to express the namespace not as a hardcoded literal which will be hard to refactor later.

Comment: I guess my point is that since there is no reference to a namespace in itself (at runtime) there is no way to get the namespace name as a string since there is nothing you can retrieve it from. You will need a type or an instance of a type within the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

For string use below code

```
    Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
    var n = myType.Namespace;

Type myType = typeof(MyClass);
Console.WriteLine("Namespace: {0}.", myType.Namespace);
```

Answer (score 2):

`nameof` is replaced at compile time with `string`, where `string` is an exact text of that member (as if you would put it yourself inside `""`).

To achieve what you want you can construct something monstrous-like:

```
namespace This.Is.My.Namespace
...
var namespaceString = $"{nameof(This)}.{nameof(This.Is)}.{nameof(This.Is.My)}.{nameof(This.Is.My.Namespace)}";
```

This will ensure what every member exists at compile-time and allow easy refactoring of either (well, unless you decide to add/delete some names).

P.S.: but obviously other answers are more *efficient* at generating same string.

Comment: Clever, but really hard to read and to type. It's a step closer to my goal though.